# Date class in an IF statement

Tags: java, date, if-statement, string-concatenation

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import type.lib.GlobalCredit;
import type.lib.CreditCard;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class eCheck08A
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintStream out = System.out;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        GlobalCredit credit1 = new GlobalCredit().getRandom();

        out.print("Enter report range in years ... ");
        int range = in.nextInt();
        out.println("Cards expiring before " + range + " year(s) from now: ");

        SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        for (CreditCard cc : credit1)
        {
            out.print(cc.getNumber());
            out.println("\t" + sf.format(cc.getExpiryDate()));
        }   
    }
}
```

At first, my app asks for Range years, lets say we enter "3". I want to put a " * " beside my date of any Year that is below the range number. Im assuming Java assumes that the date is as of today, so July 23, 2012. So for example, if we get 16/04/2013, I want a " * " beside it. But if we get 23/05/2016, no " * " to appear.

Edited:

```
  Date endDate = new Date(2015, 12, 31);
    for (CreditCard cc : credit1)
    {
        if (cc.getExpiryDate().compareTo(endDate) < 0)
        {
            if(cc.getExpiryDate().compareTo(endDate) > 0)
            {
                out.print("*");
            }
            out.print(cc.getNumber());
            out.println("\t" + sf.format(cc.getExpiryDate()));
                     }
            }
```

the range is the

Comment: You need to refer to the methods in the `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compareTo in java allows you to compare two objects. So if you compare two dates you can see which one is later or earlier. I would put some if statements in your for loop.

for example

```
Date endDate= new Date(2015, 12, 25);



for (//some stuff....)
{
     if (cc.getExpiryDate.compareTo(endDate)<0)
     {
         if (cc.getExpiryDate.compareTo(//????????? figure out which date should go here) >0)
         {  
               // put a star here
         }
      }
 }
```

when you do .compareTo if the number your comparing to is greater you will get a negative integer returned otherwise it will be positive if your object is larger. It will be zero if they are equal. Thats why people do <0 , >0 or ==0

Comment: if i create an int, and enter as 2015 and thats my endDate. that should work, right?

Comment: this is what i get: eCheck08A.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
                        if (cc.getDate().compareTo(endDate) < 0)
                              ^
  symbol:   method getDate()
  location: variable cc of type CreditCard

Comment: eCheck08A.java:26: error: method compareTo in class Date cannot be applied to gi
ven types;
                        if (cc.getExpiryDate().compareTo(endDate) < 0)
                                              ^
  required: Date
  found: SimpleDateFormat
  reason: actual argument SimpleDateFormat cannot be converted to Date by method
 invocation conversion

Comment: SimpleDateFormat endDate = new SimpleDateFormat("12/25/2015"); ?

Comment: oh here we go I think your .getExpiryDate() method is returning a regular Date. So instead of SimpleDateFormat x = new SimpleDateFormat("12/25/2015");

Do this  Date endDate= new Date(2015, 12, 25);

Comment: the endDate is suppose to be whatever the user enters. So if its "3", 2012 + 3 = 2015. so " * " should appear on any date less than 2015. endDate is not a fixed Date. "range" is when the user enters it.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is homework, I won't give you the full code.

The Java Date class allows one to compare two dates using the [`.compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29) method.  Try creating a date that's exactly `range` years in the future and finding if the credit card's expiration date is later than that.

Comment: dont i have to create a IF statement in my FOR statement?

Comment: can u pleaseeeee just give me part of the code. not even full

Comment: @user1519192: You won't learn anything that way.  Do you really want to graduate and compete for jobs against people who actually cared?

Comment: lol. im not even in computer science major. i just took computer science as an elective.

Comment: Still not an excuse.  If I wrote your code for you (no matter how many "e"s you put in please) it's still plagiarism, which is illegal, and against your school's code.